# Grafana - Dashboard title cannot be empty

Tags: prometheus, grafana

when i am trying to import JSON file into Grafana it is giving me "Dashboard title cannot be empty"

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the title in the "dashbard" section? Error is pretty clear